# PopupMenu aparecendo no topo da tela

Tags: java, android, popup

Fiz uma implementação de um `PopupMenu` sendo chamada dentro de um `Adapter` de uma `ListView`, o erro que esta acontecendo é que quando eu chamo o `PopupMenu`, o mesmo está sendo exibido no topo da `Activity`. O correto é exibir na linha que eu cliquei da `ListView`.

Segue o código:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }

        //Grava o context do aplicativo
        mContext = convertView.getContext();

        //Inicializando os componentes da item_atividade.xml
        ImageView ivIcone = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_atividade_iv_icone);
        TextView tvID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_atividade_tv_id);
        TextView tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_atividade_tv_titulo);
        TextView tvDetalhes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_atividade_tv_descricao);

        //Inicializa os componentes de click
        llmenupopup = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_atividade_ll_menu);
        ivMenupopup = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_atividade_iv_menupopup);

        //Método de click do popup da listwiew
        llmenupopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Menu popup
                ivMenupopup.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menupopup);
                final PopupMenu mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, ivMenupopup);
                mPopupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                mPopupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_atividades, mPopupMenu.getMenu());
```

Comment: Olá o problema foi resolvido da seguinte forma:

//Menu popup
                ivMenupopup.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menupopup);
                final PopupMenu mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);